# How to insert values in table in web sql?

Tags: jquery, sql, html

I am trying to insert values in a table in web sql. However, the values are not being stored in the table. Here's my code snippet:

```
var db = window.openDatabase("JCIDb", "1.0", "JCIDb", 1000000);
    db.transaction(
        function (tx) {
            tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MobileUsers (Username, Password, Image)', []);
            tx.executeSql('insert into MobileUsers values (\'' + username + '\', \'' + password + '\', \'' + ProfilePic + '\')', []);
        });
```

But when I remove the third column, i.e. Image then the values are getting stored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var db = openDatabase('mydb', '1.0', 'Test DB', 2 * 1024 * 1024);
db.transaction(function (tx) {
tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MobileUsers (username unique,password,Image blob)');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MobileUsers (username,password,Image) VALUES ("abc", "foobar","image1.jpg")');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MobileUsers (id,password,Image) VALUES ("xyz", "logmsg","image2.jpg")');
}
```

Comment: username, password and ProfilePic are variables. What's wrong in my solution? Any syntax error?

Comment: then the problem is in image

Comment: can use like this CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MobileUsers (username unique,password,Image blob)

Comment: The problem was the size of the database. I increased the size and it worked. Thanks